# How can i access download Folder in codeigniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am facing using in accessing files in Codeigniter. I will explain using examples. Suppose I have  an Xampp folder in c drive and my project is running fine and I am trying to access D drive folder and that folder has  some  PDF so I have I access ??

```
<a target="_blank"
            href="'.fopen('D:/pdf_file/demo.pdf', "r").'"><i class="fa fa-eye text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**Note - My project is in C drive**

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how HTML hyperlinks work. The value in the `href` needs to be a **URL**. Your code is attempting to pass it a PHP file handle object (as [returned by fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), which makes no sense at all. A web page cannot use a file pointer. You need to give it a string containing a URL for where the browser can go to find the document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#href

Comment: your pdf files shoud be hosted in xampp, or try using streams to get the data inside them

Comment: To make your folder acccessible through the webserver, if it's not part of the site's root then you'll need to configure your webserver with a virtual folder or site so it can serve the documents.

Answer (score 1):

The `href` attribute on `<a>` elements in HTML cannot execute PHP code such as `fopen()` directly. The href attribute in HTML only functions to specify a URL or link that will be opened when the user clicks on it.

To display a PDF file in the browser, you can use the `<a>` element with the `href` attribute pointing directly to the URL of the PDF file that can be accessed by the browser. For example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com/demo.pdf">PDF Link</a>
```

It's important to note that URLs like `D:/pdf_file/demo.pdf` in the href attribute will not work properly because it is a local file path on your system.

I suggest you to create a functional link, the PDF file needs to be hosted and accessed through a network-accessible URL, such as `https://www.example.com/demo.pdf`.

And if you want to download the source you can just simply add `download` attribute to the `<a>` tag as you can see below :

```
<a target="_blank" download href="https://www.example.com/demo.pdf">PDF Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using the fopen() function to open a PDF file located at D:/pdf_file/demo.pdf (especially for href of a tag).

The href attribute is used to specify the URL of the page or resource that the link points to.

If you want to access files outside of your CodeIgniter project directory, you need to use the correct absolute path to that directory in your code. You can use the realpath() function to get the absolute path of a directory or file on your server.

Hope this will help you!